# Changing background-image of div via click on another div

Tags: jquery, html, css, background-image

First of all my code can be found here in total.

http://jsfiddle.net/yfukm8kh/1/

The part I'm having problems with is the following.

```
var changePic = function (direction, id, array) {

    var intID = parseInt(id);
    var intDir = parseInt(direction);
    if (intID > 0) {
        intID = intID + intDir;
        currentID = intID;
        alert(array[intID].link);
        $('#lightbox').css("background-image", array[intID].link);
    } else if (intID == 0 && intDir == 1) {
        intID = intID + intDir;
        currentID = intID;
        alert(array[intID].link);
        $('#lightbox').css("background-image", array[intID].link);
    }
};
```

What I want this function to do is changing the `background-image` of the `div id=lightbox` to one with the `URL` in the `array` I'm giving the function.

However when I click on the sidebars the whole `<div id=lightbox>`is removed again as if I had clicked on the `div` itself() and not on the sidebar. However if I put an `alert` inside the `function` it shows that the `event` was triggered and at least some code inside the `function` was executed.

I'm now assuming that when I click on the sidebar I'm triggering two events, the one that would change the `background-image` and one that `removes` the `lightbox` again.

Is there any way to prevent the underlying `div` from "listening" to the click?

Also, please correct me if I'm using any terms incorrectly or my posting etiquette is off. I'm new to all of this and would appreciate the input from experienced users.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to stop event propagation using [**stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) in the side bar events:

### event.stopPropagation():

> > Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

### Code:

```
$(document).on('click', '#leftBar', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        changePic(-1, currentID, activeArray);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#rightBar', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        changePic(1, currentID, activeArray);
    });
```

### UPDATED FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/yfukm8kh/3/

You should read about [**Event Bubbling and Propagation**](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/event_capturing_bubbling_javascript.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly. I guess I'll have to dive into events a little more.

Comment: yes you should understand ``preventDefault()`` and ``stopPropogation()``

Answer (score 0):

So you only want to address `#lightbox`, right? Not what's inside it?
Try this:

```
$('body > #lightbox').css("background-image", array[intID].link);
```

Comment: Sorry that might have been misleading, I want to click on `#lightboxBar` and not `#lightbox`.

Answer (score 0):

- to prevent triggering click event for `#lightbox` you can use `return false;` in right and left bar handlers.
- I moved `#lightbox` click handler out of `.singapore` click handler to prevent miltiple adding of this handler.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfukm8kh/2/).

```
$(document).on('click', '#leftBar', function () {
    changePic(-1, currentID, activeArray);
    return false;
});

$(document).on('click', '#rightBar', function () {
    changePic(1, currentID, activeArray);
    return false;
});

$('.singapore').click(function () {
    currentID = event.target.id;
    openThumbnail(singaporeArray, currentID);
});

$(document).on('click', '#lightbox', function () {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried it and it worked. Would you mind explaining to me why this works? I have an idea but I'm not sure if it works the way I think it does. Also thanks for the hint regarding the `#lightbox` click handler. I also implemented that.

Comment: @Joachihm take a look at most popular answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false). In shortly, `return false;` in jQuery event handler prevents calling other handlers in chain. So event handler for `'#lightbox'` will not be called after `'#rightBar'` one.

Comment: Thanks again. Very interesting read. It's pretty much what I had guessed.